# jqGrid: Do not allow selecting a row in the grid without the others are updated

Tags: jqgrid

I'm working with two grids. When a line of the first grid is selected, the second grid is reloading.

So,I wanted it was not possible to select a line of the first grid while the second is not reloading.

Answer (score 0):

I am not full understand what you mean under updating of the second grid, but to if you just need to prevent row selection in the grid under some condition you need implement [beforeSelectRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents#list_of_events) callback:

```js
beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
    if (/*test some criteria*/) {
        return false; // prevent row selection
    }
    return true; // allow row selection
}
```

Comment: @fmassica: Why the second grid will be updated? Do you implemented some master/details scenario? In any way either you can follow my suggestion with blocking of selection of new rows in `beforeSelectRow` till the detail grid is loaded or you can just block the full master grid during loading of the second. Look what do `loadui: 'block'` setting. You can enable (make visible) the overlay of the first grid in `beforeRequest` of the second grid and hide it inside of `loadComplete` or `loadError`.

Comment: The second grid is loaded when a line of the first grid is selected by onSelectRow.